# Tox.ini does not recognize python folder?

Tags: python, django, mypy, tox, flake8

I ran into weird issue which I have trouble solving. I have following tox.ini file:

```
[vars]
PROJECT = django_project
TASKS = tasks --exclude tasks/migrations
PAGES = pages -exclude pages/migrations

[tox]
envlist = py310, flake8, black, mypy

[testenv]
deps =
    -rrequirements.txt
    -rrequirements-dev.txt

commands = python manage.py test

[testenv:flake8]
basepython=python3
deps =
    -rrequirements-dev.txt
commands= python -m flake8 --max-line-length=100 {[vars]PROJECT} {[vars]TASKS} {[vars]PAGES}
whitelist_externals = /usr/bin/python3

[testenv:black]
deps = -rrequirements-dev.txt
commands = black --check --diff {[vars]PROJECT} {[vars]TASKS} {[vars]PAGES}


[testenv:mypy]
deps =
    -rrequirements-dev.txt
commands = mypy --install-types --non-interactive \
                --ignore-missing-imports \
                --disallow-untyped-defs \
                --disallow-incomplete-defs \
                --disallow-untyped-decorators {[vars]PROJECT} {[vars]TASKS} {[vars]PAGES}
```

The black commands works as expected for PAGES, but the commands flake8 and mypy are returning following error: `error: unrecognized arguments: pages -exclude pages/migrations`

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Yes, it's more of shell issue than `python`. Try running `mypy foo --exclude bar "foo --exclude bar"` and watch the error message (mind the <s>gap</s>quotes!). `tox` expands every variable as being a **single** argument. I'm not sure that `tox.ini` has any array expansion capabilities, so your idea may be impossible to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your configuration...

```
TASKS = tasks --exclude tasks/migrations
PAGES = pages -exclude pages/migrations
```

It has to be `--exclude`, not `-exclude`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but it still does not fix it unfortunatly

Comment: Do you get a new error message? flake8 understands `--exclude`. I just tried it on my computer.

Comment: It's the same message. I get the same message even when I remove the --exclude.